# acute accent beside dot?

Tags: accents

How can I get an acute accent and a dot over a letter without one appearing above the other? All I have been able to produce is béġu. I want both the acute and the dot above the letter e, side by side.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what is meant?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\newcommand\acutedot[1]{%
  \stackengine{.5pt}{#1}{\footnotesize\raisebox{-.8pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle\prime$}%
    \kern-.8pt.\kern-.3pt}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\begin{document}
b\acutedot{e}gu
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is one with slightly different metrics, but which works across [most] font size changes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\newcommand\acutedot[1]{%
  \stackengine{.12ex}{#1}{\raisebox{-.18ex}{$\scriptscriptstyle\prime$}%
    \kern-.1em.\kern-.07em}{O}{c}{F}{T}{S}}
\begin{document}
b\acutedot{e}gu
\scriptsize b\acutedot{e}gu
\huge b\acutedot{e}gu
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the standard accents:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\acutedotsym}{%
  \kern-.2em\'{}\kern-.25em\raisebox{-.15ex}[0pt][0pt]{\.{}}\kern-.05em
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\acutedot}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{
    \offinterlineskip
    \ialign{%
      \hfil##\hfil\cr
      \hidewidth\acutedotsym\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern-1ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\'e\acutedot{e}e\'i\acutedot{\i}iA\acutedot{A}A

eeeiiiAAA
\end{document}
```

[image]